# Can i access /data/user/0/ folder from ubuntu?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using ubuntu 18.04.
From android studio with this following code i am getting file directory

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
final File filesDir = ctx.getFilesDir();
```

which is `/data/user/0/com.example.ipfs/files/` . I am running my app on android emulator. How do i go to the `/data/user/0/com.example.ipfs/files/` folder from my pc? I want to go to that location from my ubuntu directory and view files.

Comment: If the Device Explorer of Android Studio does not show that directory then you are out of possibilities.

Comment: @blackapps how do i check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to go to that folder in your ubunto.

Simple click on `Navigate` and `Search everywhere`, then type "Device File Explorer".

[image]

After you open it, you should be able to find all of the emulator folders.